# How to collect tweets outside a given bounding box?

Tags: api, extents, twitter

I checked the twitter API [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters).

I know how to get tweets in United States within a bounding box such as:

```
[-124.47,24.0,-66.56,49.3843].
```

How can I easily get all the tweets NOT in this bounding box?

Answer (score 1):

Textually from the Twitter [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters)

> If you would like to exclude place matches or only include places
>   which fall completely within the bounding box, your code will have to
>   perform an additional filtering step after reading the filtered
>   stream.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a dataframe from raw tweet data file and then filter using coordinates as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
from tweet_parser.tweet import Tweet
from tweet_parser.tweet_parser_errors import NotATweetError
import fileinput
import json
```

## CONVERT RAW TEXT FILE TO JSON FILE

```
with open('tweet_stream.txt') as infile, open('tweet_stream.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip(): continue  # skip the empty line
        outfile.write(line)  # non-empty line. Write it to output
```

## WRITE JSON FILE INTO A PANDAS DATAFRAME

```
df  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DateTime','user_id','lat','long','tweet'])
for line in fileinput.FileInput("tweet_stream.json"):
    try:
        tweet_dict = json.loads(line)
        tweet = Tweet(tweet_dict)
    except (json.JSONDecodeError,NotATweetError):
        pass

    if tweet.geo_coordinates is None:
        df= df.append({'DateTime':tweet.created_at_datetime,'user_id':tweet.user_id,'lat':tweet.geo_coordinates,'long':tweet.geo_coordinates,'tweet':tweet.text},ignore_index=True)
    else:
        df= df.append({'DateTime':tweet.created_at_datetime,'user_id':tweet.user_id,'lat':tweet.geo_coordinates['latitude'],'long':tweet.geo_coordinates['longitude'],'tweet':tweet.text},ignore_index=True)
```

## APPLY LOCATION FILTER

```
latmin = 24.0
latmax = 49.3843
longmin = -124.47
longmax = -66.56

df_geo = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DateTime','user_id','lat','long','tweet'])
geo = df['lat'].notnull() #filtering out non-geotagged tweets
df_geo = df[geo].reset_index(drop=True)
loc_filter = (df_geo['lat'] < latmin) & (df_geo['lat'] > latmax) & (df_geo['long'] < longmin) & (df_geo['long'] > longmax)
df_geo = df_geo[loc_filter].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Note that this code is able to filter only geotagged tweets (tweets which have a coordinates field as Type: Point) and disregards tweets which are streamed as a result of the overlap between the 'place' polygon and provided bounding box, eg.[-124.47,24.0,-66.56,49.3843].

I hope this helps.